# IBOutlets for custom UIView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, iboutlet

I have a simple application, in which there is a view controller which is inited with nib file. In this nib file I have a simple View who's parent class is a `customUIView` subclass of `UIView`. In this view there are some buttons which I want to access on my custom `UIView` subclass methods when the `setNeedDisplay` method is called. Is it good practice to create `IBOutlets` for these buttons in both `customUIView` and `customUIViewcontroller` classes, or should I access these buttons by iterating on `self.subviews`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the IBOutlets indeed... since this is the best way to acces these buttons properties.